# Linux close virtualenv after exiting terminal

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

I recently created a virtual environment for running a website using the flask library. However, I decided not to use a virtual environment and accidentally closed the terminal I ran it with (I used the "virtualenv [name of virtualenv] -p python3 " command) and deleted the folder it was in. I read online that that was not a problem, but I wanted to make sure. So is that ok, or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: If you deleted the venv folder, there is nothing to worry about. Python environment is attached to the current session of your terminal. So, if you closed the terminal, your next session will be set back to the default python installation on your machine (usually, `/usr/bin/python3` or `/bin/python3`). You can confirm this by typing: `where python`. Also, virtual environments are self-contained. So, if you just delete the folder with `rm -rf FOLDER_NAME`, you have successfully, wiped any trace of it.

Comment: However, just to be safe; first deactivate your current active environment by typing `deactivate` (or `conda deactivate` - in case you created environment using an Anaconda installation), and then deleting by `rm -rf FOLDER_NAME.

Comment: Your welcome. Have a nice day!